# An inquiry regarding Euler's disk

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

In this video that explains some math behind Euler's  Disk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pSLffliCk0&t=367s I don't get why the ratio of the leftover part of the circumference to the circumference represents the ratio of the spinning to the wobbling. Can anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 0):

After one revolution around the small radius, one wobble, the disk will not have rotated all the way around.

If the black mark on the disk starts pointing down to the table, the "leftover part of the circumference" will be how far the black marker line now is from its start position - i.e. how far it moved due to the rotation.